# Apache changing AllowOverride made my server fail

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

http://ec2-54-243-158-66.compute-1.amazonaws.com

I was following a tutorial and right after I did this, my server stopped responding:

```
sudo su

vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

find the line:
`AllowOverride None` - after the (about line 339 or so...)

change to `AllowOverride All` (case matters! All not all or ALL)

`:wq` to save

service httpd restart

I reverted everything back to exactly what it was and it still wont work.

Edit: http://stephen-white.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-set-up-wordpress-on-amazon-ec2_31.html  This was the tutorial I was following, everything worked until I made that change suggested by a comment at the bottom that allowed wordpress to modify the .htaccess for permalinks

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: I personally don't know how to read system logs haha I uploaded it here: http://ec2-54-243-158-66.compute-1.amazonaws.com/log.txt

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I've installed WordPress and other PHP applications on AWS before many times with no issues.  The comment on there for AllowOverride was relating to using a specific kind of permalink.  Were you trying to enable that permalink format?

Comment: your server isn't up so we can't read your logs. just look for error messages in the apache log file (all logs are in /var/log). If you like you can rename the current log file and restart apache to get a clean log which will make it easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you have figured this out by now, but I will share a very helpful command:
httpd -S 
This will syntax check your configuration files for you. It may give you a clue as to why apache will not start.  The /var/log/httpd/error_log should also have helpful information.